# Connect multiple rabbitMQ to each other

Tags: rabbitmq

I have been searching, and I couldn't find if it is possible to connect two rabbitmq instances together. I am thinking of this as an alternative to RabbitMQ Clustering feature.

My goal is that for each message that a broker receives, it routes to another broker. Does the exchange or queues in rabbitMQ allow to have this architecture?

Producer -> Broker <-> Broker -> Consumer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exchange federation](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/rabbitmq-federation.html) to publish to both the original broker and another (downstream) broker.